# JSF + Primefaces atualizar componente ao trocar paginação

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

```
    <p:dataList paginator="true" value="{bean.lista}"
                        var="lista">
    </:dataList>

<h:outputText value="qualquerCoisa" id="teste"/>
```

Como eu faço pra atualizar o outputText 'teste' toda vez que a pagina do dataList mudar? , exemplo paginação 1,2,3,4[...] quando o usuario mudar da página 1 para a página 2 atualizar o componente 'teste', quando trocar pra outra pagina qualquer atualizar novamente?
O componente deve estar fora do dataList ou dataTable e tem que ser ao mudar a paginação, sem botoes ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segue um exemplo:

```
<p:dataTable var="variavel" paginator="true" rows="1" value="#{myBean.list}">
  <p:ajax event="page" update="buttons" listener="#{myBean.update}" />
  ...
</p:dataTable>
```

aqui o método que vai atualizar o teu cara:

```
public void update(PageEvent event) {
  int var = event.getPage();
  ...
  (aqui você atualiza a variavel do seu componente)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Apenas com o <p:ajax event="page" update="buttons" /> já funcionou como eu queria, também foi preciso alterar o <h:form> e colocar prependID="true". Obrigado